# How to use NormalizeString() in Visual C++ 6.0?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm doing on a project that currently on VC6.0, under Windows 7.

I want to use `NormalizeString` method and tried Microsoft's [this sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319092(v=vs.85).aspx), which is working fine in Visual Studio 2015, but will not compile in VC6.0.

When I build a sample project I get these errors:

```
error C2065: 'NORM_FORM' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'NormalizationC' : undeclared identifier
```

Is there anything I am missing in VC6.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LoadLibrary() to load Normaliz.dll (sic).  Then use GetProcAddress() to get a pointer to the function.  then just use the pointer as if it were the function name.  There is a bit more to it, but that is the basic process for manually loading a dynamic library.

Also, you should download Visual Studio 2017 Free Version.  Its really good, supports 64 bit executables, and its free from Microsoft.

Comment: If I use `LoadLibrary(L"normaliz.dll")`, I got error code 193 "not a valid Win32 application".

Comment: Update: I fould only normaliz.dll version 6.3.9600.16384 work for VC6.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum supported client for this API is a Windows Vista. MSVC6 has been released long before it. You at least have to install [Windows Vista Platform SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14477).

Comment: Installed the SDK but still have the same error. Do I need extra configuring?

Comment: @Dia Sure. You should configure your project to use installed Platform SDK instead of default. Change include and library paths for all configurations and rebuild solution.

Comment: @Dia: Yes. Since the Vista SDK could _also_ target Windows 2000 and XP, you'll need to configure it to target exactly Vista. Since this is so antique, I don't recall the details how to do it.

Comment: I added `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Include` to include path, also similarly for \bin and \lib, but still get compiling fail.